# jquery performing a selector on an element variable

Tags: jquery, variables, element, selector

I'm having difficulty with performing a selector operation on an element variable.  First I'm selecting my table element in my page using jquery.

```
var $popup = null;
$popup = $("#popup_List");

<div id="popup" class="popup_block">
    <table id="popup_List"><tr><td>Name</td></tr></table>
</div>
```

I'm trying to perform a selector operation on the `$popup` variable.  The following does not work

```
$popup("tr:last").after("<tr><td>Name</td></tr");
```

I'd like to use the variable approach because `$("#popup_List")` would have to be referenced numerous times in the code otherwise.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

`$popup.find("tr:last").after("<tr><td>Name</td></tr");`

Answer (score 4):

```
var last = $("tr:last", popup);
```

just pass in the context for the jquery() method.

Answer (score 1):

You don't need to prefix with $ on your variable, only when you are instantiating the jquery object:

```
var popup = $("#popup_List");
var last = popup.find("tr:last");
```

By the way, it is odd that you have the 'L' in List capitalized. This might lead to bugs, so I'd go with `popup_list` for consistency.

Comment: True, but this can helpful to developers so they know it is in fact a jQuery object.

Comment: Hm, good point. Just wanted to make sure the asker knew it wasn't required.